Why does phasor multiplication produce a different result with actual sine multiplication?
I thought phasors were shortcuts to the Euler's formula when dealing with sine functions.
For example,
$$\begin{align}\cos(t+a)+\cos(t+b)&=Re\{e^{j(t+a)}+e^{j(t+b)}\}\\
&=Re\{e^{jt}[(\cos a + \cos b)+j(\sin a+\sin b)]\}\\
&=Re\{e^{jt}[\sqrt{A^2+B^2}(\cos \theta+j\sin\theta)]\}\\
&=\sqrt{A^2+B^2}Re\{e^{j(t+\theta)}\}\\
&=\sqrt{A^2+B^2}\cos(t+\theta)\end{align}$$
The RHS can be shortened as
$$\angle a + \angle b = \sqrt{A^2+B^2}\angle \theta$$
But then, I got confusing results for multiplication.
$$\cos(t+a)\cos(t+b)\to\angle a \angle b = \angle(a+b)\to\cos(t+a+b)$$
However,
$$\cos(t+a)\cos(t+b)=\frac12[\cos(2t+a+b)+\cos(a-b)]$$
Why does the path using phasors produce a different result with actual multiplication?

1. Current and voltage
Products like \$\sin(\omega t) \cos(\omega t)\$ or \$\sin(\omega t) \sin(\omega t)\$ or \$\cos(\omega t) \cos(\omega t)\$ generate other terms (trigonometric functions) with twice the value of original frequency \$\omega\$. Phasor analysis is not involved with this type of operation, when applied to impedances and steady-state sinusoidal currents and voltages.
For example, let a be the voltage phasor \$\textbf{V}\$, given the impedance \$\textbf{Z}\$ and current \$\textbf{I}\$:
$$\textbf{V}=\textbf{Z I}$$
This is the same as writing:
$$V_{ef}e^{j \theta_v}=\frac{V_{ef}}{I_{ef}}e^{j(\theta_v - \theta_i)} \space I_{ef} \space e^{j \theta_i}$$
where \$V_{ef}\$ and \$I_{ef}\$ are the RMS values for the voltage and current, and \$\theta_v\$ and \$\theta_i\$ are the corresponding angles. Multiplying both sides by \$e^{jt}\$ (since you are using \$\omega= 1 \space \mathrm{rad/s}\$):
$$V_{ef}e^{j(t+\theta_v)}=\frac{V_{ef}}{I_{ef}}e^{j(\theta_v - \theta_i)} \space I_{ef} \space e^{j(t + \theta_i)}$$
Taking the real part:
$$\mathrm{Re} \left\{ V_{ef}e^{j(t+\theta_v)} \right\} = \mathrm{Re} \left\{\frac{V_{ef}}{I_{ef}}e^{j(\theta_v - \theta_i)} \space I_{ef} \space e^{j(t + \theta_i)} \right\}=V_{ef}\cos(t + \theta_v)$$
Thus, it is possible to verify that at no time was there a multiplication of functions of that referred types. Just that phasor, as the result of a product, represents a complex number whose module is the product of the modules and the angle is the sum of the angles of the factors.
2. Power
Your identity
$$\cos(t+a) \space \cos(t+b) = \frac{1}{2}\left[ \cos(2t+a+b))+\cos(a-b) \right] \qquad (1)$$
is correct. But, as I already mentioned, this has nothing to do with phasors. On the other hand, products, for example involving \$\cos() \cos()\$, can occur in the power calculation, for example.
In the left side of \$(1)\$, let \$\cos(t + a)\$ and \$\cos(t + b) \$ to represent the voltage and current through a complex load with module \$1 \space \Omega\$
(frequency \$\omega=1 \space \mathrm{rad/s} \longrightarrow \mathrm{T}=2\pi \space \mathrm{s}\$), then the mean power is:
$$
\begin{aligned}
  \mathrm{P} &= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int^{2\pi}_{0} \cos(t+a) \cos(t+b) dt = \frac{1}{2\pi} 
  \int^{2\pi}_{0} \frac{1}{2}\left[ \cos(2t+a+b)+\cos(a-b) \right ] dt \\
  \\
  \mathrm{P} &= \frac{1}{2}\cos(a-b)
\end{aligned}
$$
That integral would not even need to be solved. It's enough to look in righ side of \$(1)\$, to notice the mean value (DC) is \$\frac{1}{2}\cos(a-b)\$.
The plot below shows the instantaneous power, according \$(1)\$; also pointing out a mean power of \$0.25 \space \mathrm{W}\$, for \$a = 0 \space \mathrm{rad}\$ and  and \$b = 60/180\pi \space \mathrm{rad}\$.


A phasor can be represented by a complex number. The magnitude of the phasor is the magnitude of the complex number, and the angle of the phasor is the arctangent of the imaginary part over the real part (or possibly vice-versa depending upon one's conventions).
The product of two complex numbers is given by
$$(a + jb)(c + jd) = (ac - bd) + j(ad + bc)$$
And, so it is with phasors.

Note that we can use phasor multiplication in a phasor version of Ohm's law.
$$\mathbf{V} = \mathbf{I}\mathbf{Z}$$
However, because the instantaneous power in a linear circuit occurs at twice the frequency of either the voltage or the current, we CANNOT use phasor multiplication for something like this:
$$\mathbf{P} = \mathbf{V}\mathbf{I}$$
The above equation makes sense in terms of instantaneous values, but not as a phasor equation.

Phasors are linear transformations of pure steady-state sinusoidal signals with a single frequency. Phasor(A+B) = Phasor(A)+Phasor(B) and Phasor(kA)=kPhasor(A) where A and B are sinusoidal signals at the same frequency and k is a real or complex constant which can depend on frequency, but doesn't evolve along the time.
But you asked "Why Phasor(AB) generally is not the same as Phasor(A)Phasor(B)?" Math facts happens to be so and you have just proved it. The error is made by those who believe that generally Phasor(AB) = Phasor(A)Phasor(B).
